# Bash comparison operator always true

Tags: bash, if-statement, compare

I'm trying to write a small script to compare my external IP (first three bytes) with the one below:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYFILE=/home/me/.config/i3/pia
while true
do
    IP_EX=$(wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO - | cut -d"." -f1,2,3) 
    if [[ "$IP_EX"=="173.199.65" ]]
    then
        echo file created
        touch $MYFILE 
    else
        echo file deleted
        rm -f $MYFILE   
    fi
    echo sleeping
    sleep 4
done
```

This always returns `file created`, and the else statement is never executed. This is the case *even* if I replace the `$IP_EX` with `whatever`. Why is that?

Comment: Still returning as true :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash commands are sensitive to spaces.  You need to add spaces around `==`.

Observe that this gives the wrong answer:

```
$ IP_EX=abc; [[ "$IP_EX"=="173.199.65" ]] && echo True
True
```

By contrast, this version, with spaces, works correctly:

```
$ IP_EX=abc; [[ "$IP_EX" == "173.199.65" ]] && echo True
$
```

The problem is that bash sees `"$IP_EX"=="173.199.65"` as a single string.  When given such a single argument, `[[` returns true if the string is not empty and false if it is empty:

```
$ [[ "" ]] && echo True
$ [[ "1" ]] && echo True
True
```

With the spaces added in, bash sees `"$IP_EX" == "173.199.65"` as three arguments with the middle argument being `==`.  It therefore tests for equality.  This is what you want.